# Declaring function in Blocks in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6

I am facing an issue in declaring a fucation in block which I have added . I am calling a function by including an file which ia placed in the theme. I have also tried it by placing out of the theme folder. The function is alredy being user in front page. But when I am using the same function in that block. The screen gets blank and nothing displays. some part of my block coding is written below. Please help me.

```
<?php
global $base_url;
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/travellar/geoiploc.php"); // indluded file
$ip = "203.189.25.0"; // Australia IP test
$country_code = getCountryFromIP($ip, "code");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had no problems loading functions from modules into custom blocks, but I've never tried loading one from a theme before. It's not clear to me whether or not theme functions are loaded before the page content is loaded.

You might have to create a custom module or include file to hold the function. Check out the module_load_include() function for how to load a specific include file.

Comment: Another possibility is to directly use the standard php statement "include_once ".

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I have placed this file in the root folder. I have tried with the module_load_include() function, but I am not able to use this function correctly. I am getting Fatal Error: Cannot redeclare the function .

Comment: That error means that the function name is already in use, probably the one [two] you added. So, remove one of the instances of the function definition or use a different function name.

Answer (score 0):

A custom module would be a good approach as it is loaded before the theme layer and can be accessed from almost anywhere in Drupal except other modules with a lower weight than the custom module. It is also likely to come in handy for hooks and other overrides.

However, if you must have it in the theme layer, another option is adding it to template.php of your theme which should make it available within page.tpl.php and such, but not blocks I don't believe.

/sites/all/modules/mymodule/mymodule.info

```
name = My Module
package = !
description = It is MY module, not yours! 
core = 6.x
```

The package "!" will make this module appear at the top of the modules page

/sites/all/modules/mymodule/mymodule.module

```
<?php

  // Load mymodule.morePHP.inc
  module_load_include('inc', 'mymodule', 'mymodule.morePHP');

  // A custom function
  function mymodule_my_custom_function($args) {
    /* do custom stuff here */
    return 'output';
  }
```

/sites/all/modules/mymodule/mymodule.morePHP.inc

```
<?php

  // An included custom function
  function mymodule_other_custom_stuff() {

  }
```